# The 'Avg. Time on Page' is zero on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to trace and analyze my website, but i found more than 90% of 'Avg. Time on Page' is zero(see the screen shot below). I searched a lot and found most of the answers are the user closed that page directly and didn't go to next page so the 'Avg. Time on Page' is zero, but i am sure this is not my case. 
Could any body know the reason or any clue? Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you sure that it is not your case?